# Is there a difference between chaining EMFEditProperties methods vs. using FeaturePath.fromList?

Tags: jface, emf, eclipse-databinding

Is there any difference between

```
EMFEditProperties.list(
        editingDomain,
        FeaturePath.fromList(DemoPackage.Literals.TRANSPORT_DETAILS__SELECTED_TRANSPORT,
            DemoPackage.Literals.TRANSPORT__DEPARTURES))
```

and

```
EMFEditProperties
        .value(editingDomain, DemoPackage.Literals.TRANSPORT_DETAILS__SELECTED_TRANSPORT)
        .list(DemoPackage.Literals.TRANSPORT__DEPARTURES)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

From studying the sourcecode of EMFEditProperties, I think there is no difference. In fact, if you use a feature path with more than one element, the implementation uses the chained form internally.